# Getting Row percentages in python to plot

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

Hi I am looking to create some kind of frequency table where i can get row (or column) percentages, with the purpose of being able to plot the data side by side in a bar chart. The output would look something like this:

```
       Male  Female
 Mon   21%     79%
 Tues  33%     67%
 Weds  11%     89%
```

Currently my data looks like this:

```
Day  Gender
Mon  Male
Mon  Female
Mon  Female
Weds Female
Fri  Male
```

In the end I just want 5 bar plots (one for each day) with two bars for each gender. I tried groupby:

```
df.groupby(['day','gender']).size()
```

But this only gives raw counts and both histograms are uninterpretable and bar plots will look weird since I cannot normalize (certain days have much higher volumes than other days). any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do your groupby above, you then need to unstack the results (which makes a pivot table).

```
gb = df.groupby(['Day','Gender']).size().unstack()
>>> gb
Gender    Female      Male
Day                       
Fri          NaN  1.000000
Mon     0.666667  0.333333
Weds    1.000000       NaN
```

You may wish to fill NaNs with zeros (`.fillna(0)`).

Now you can divide this result by the sum of the rows:

```
>>> gb.div(gb.sum(axis=1).values, axis=0)
Gender    Female      Male
Day                       
Fri          NaN  1.000000
Mon     0.666667  0.333333
Weds    1.000000       NaN
```

You can plot this by appending `.plot(kind='bar')`